# good heating/cooling for sunroom in Toronto

Tags: heat-pump, sunroom

I have a east facing sunroom with 2 side glass. its 10x16 feet (length/breath). The highest point of the roof is 9 feet sloping to 7 feet.
Our winter goes to -20 degrees C and hottest goes to 35 degrees C.
I am bit perplexed on what i need to use for heating and  cooling. There are many options with many price factors.
the options that is availabe is the heat pump that is approx 1-2 k depending on the model.
The alternative is portable airconditioner + electric fireplace. its roughly 1k

I am not sure how to decide between these if i ignore the price factor

Comment: Are you also ignoring the running cost? Because the more expensive to buy option will cost a lot less to run over its lifetime.

Comment: ok. the heatpump so far is higher priced to install vs the other  options.  i do expect it to be running in all the seasons either to provide heat or a/c.

Comment: Check out Passive Solar Design: we designed our house with the balcony sized to shade windows in summer and let sun through in winter. If you don’t let the energy in you don’t need to pay to move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to stay there for a while then do it properly with a heat pump.

Portable coolers are a pain to empty water out of / vent (depending on the model).  The running cost of the heat pump may be similar in winter (for your proposal) but would be better in winter.